# PHP CSV export more than 20000 records

Tags: php, csv

Giving Fatal Error in memory allocation for query reading more than 20000 records from the database and also its taking too much of time to load

So please help us good suggestion to export more than 20000 records.

Comment: What query you have used? Without seeing that no one will be able to optimize that.

Comment: you might be reading all of the records in memory before exporting. open cursor using mysql_query and then Read records one by one by mysql_fetch_assoc. See http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: I think query its not a problem but reading a data through PDO is giving problem .. Just I used simple query

Comment: Why is php a requirement? Is this a mysql database? Why not use mysqldump?

Answer (score 1):

If you are exporting that many records as Excel then the issue will be more bad than memory limit.

If you are exporting data to CSV via the PHP script then you can use the following

set_time_limit(6000);
ini_set("memory_limit", -1);

The first one will set the script limit and the 2nd one will erase the memory issue.

But its always good to avoid exporting or importing at once with huge data set, but I agree sometime we have no choice but to do as per the requirement.

Comment: its a client requirement. future it will increase to more than 30k!! is there any way to do??

Comment: Yes, you can try ini_set("memory_limit", -1); and then execute the export script. This would take time but will work. I have done the same last week when one of my export was doing more than 30k records as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Just allocate more memory and time. The default are usually low anayway. These parameters are set in php.ini, or at runtime with php. Below for setting first of all in php.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','300M'); // mem
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000); // time
```

It might however be smarter to export smaller chunks of the data. It is a more "correct" way to do this. But i realise that for such things as a one time operation/export etc, a large dump and more memory might be desirable.

Comment: I Increased memory limit :2GB .. Still its getting problem. Is there any efficient way to export ?? what are the things we need to follow to export millions of record

Comment: Try to devide the export. For instance. If you have 1m rows, Divide it in 10, and do 10 exports with 100k each. Do a read of the exported data before initiating the next export so you know what rows to export. Then it dosnt matter if the process gets halted somewhere, you just continue with the not-exported ones. Its a good thing to devide it. Since, at some point, no matter how much memory you allocate, it will be to little.

Comment: Regarding optimization. There are a lot of things that can be done, surely. You have to post the query for us to tell. But generally joins and indexes are things to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bjorn.. I have one quick question suppose if I assign millions of records in single array , while reading a each record from that array will I get any problem? at max how much I can able to store in single array?

Comment: If you have to big arrays, your memory will run out. And it will be slow. This is the limitation. Lots of rows is one thing, but lots of data in each row to, takes up space in memory.